# Combine multiple columns values to one label in chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli, chart.js

My table(tb_ticket) which like this :

| technician_1 | Technician_2 |
| --- | --- |
| Ema | Ema |
| Tom | Ema |
| Lisa | Tom |
| Ana | Lisa |
| Tom | Tom |

My question is how to make it like this :

Ema=3, Tom=4, Ana=1, Lisa=2

My query

```
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
         type: 'bar',
               data: {
                  labels: ["Ema", "Tom", "Ana", "Lisa"],
                  datasets: [{
                  label: 'Request by technician',
                  data: [  

                  <?php 
                  $technician_ema= mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from tb_ticket where (technician_1','technician_2)='Ema'");
                  echo mysqli_num_rows($technician_ema);
                  ?>, 

                  <?php 
                  $technician_tom= mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from tb_ticket where (technician_1','technician_2)='Tom'");
                  echo mysqli_num_rows($technician_tom);
                  ?>,

                  <?php 
                  $technician_ana= mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from tb_ticket where (technician_1','technician_2)='Ana'");
                  echo mysqli_num_rows($technician_ana);
                  ?>, 
                  <?php 
                  $technician_lisa= mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from tb_ticket where (technician_1','technician_2)='Lisa'");
                  echo mysqli_num_rows($technician_lisa);
                  ?>

                   ],
                   backgroundColor: [
                   '#1B4F72',
                   '#21618C',
                   '#2874A6',
                   '#2E86C1'
                    ],
                    }]
                    },
                   options: {
                       scales: {
                           xAxes: [{
                              ticks: {
                                autoSkip: false
                                }
                             }]
                            }
                           }
                        });
                 </script>
```

Combine the total number of technicians from column technician_1 and technicians_2 into a bar chart.

[My chart like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi5JD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
change the code below.

```
<?php 
$technician_lisa= mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from tb_ticket where technician_1='lisa' or technician_2='Lisa'");
echo mysqli_num_rows($technician_lisa);
?>
```